# naming dataframes that are automatically generated by a function

Tags: python

So I have a function `func(field)` that returns a `DataFrame`.

i have a list of 1000s of fields and want to loop and pass them all through the function and save each dataframe separately.

to simply here is a list of 3 fields:

```
fields = ['math','science','english']

for field in fields:
    field+df = func(field)
```

The idea is that i want to generate variables that contain the name of the field so that I can access the dataframe of any field at any time without having to loop through them all...

so it would be nice if I can just call `mathdf` or `englishdf` etc

Comment: Don't do this. If you want an association between names and values use a dictionary.

Comment: thank you @ChristianDean. I will do that. I'm still learning python, so go easy on me guys.